# send html text with ajax, problem on '&'?

Tags: html, entities

i use jquery.ajax to save a rich text area .

```
corr=some.innerHTML(); /* corr='&lt; some text &lt;' */
$.ajax({
    type:"POST", url:"flatplan/save_corr.php",
    data:"corr="+corr+"&IDFS="+IDFILES,
    success: function(msg){

    },
    error:function(x,e){
        ajax_errors(x,e);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the corr variable can contain '&' chars inside and it send more params
giving problems. Is there any way to post with ajax html text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can (and should) escape query string components [with `encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference:global_functions:encodeuricomponent).

```
data: "corr=" + encodeURIComponent(corr) + "&IDFS=" + encodeURIComponent(IDFILES),
```

Edit: jQuery can accept an Object in the data field. You should just use

```
data: ({
  corr: corr,
  IDFS: IDFILES
}),
```

so that jQuery can automatically encode the query string.

Comment: Agreed, sending the data to jquery as an object is by far the best plan. The 'data as a query string' syntax is really terrible in my opinion, and apparently it has other issues.

Answer (score 1):

The corr value cannot contain `&`. If it does, you need to urlencode that value. To do this, use the `escape()` method.

```
var corr = escape(some.innerHTML()); //(corr='&lt; some text &lt;')
$.ajax({
    type:"POST", 
    url:"flatplan/save_corr.php",
    data:"corr="+corr+"&IDFS="+IDFILES,
    success: function(msg){
        //success handler
    },
    error:function(x,e){
        ajax_errors(x,e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally escape all html going into before posting it via AJAX that and have the php file unescape the resultant or Sanity Check the input in PHP before processing. I've not been caught with this one but I can see where it might be an issue.